# Does Bootstrap 3.4.0 include any breaking changes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anybody of you know, whether Bootstrap 3.4.0 includes breaking changes (in comparison to 3.3.x)? The [announcement blog post for the version](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/12/13/bootstrap-3-4-0/) does not state one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I found two clues, that might suggest the correct answer:

1. Bootstrap promises to follow the Semantic Versioning standard: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#versioning
2. The Upgrade documentation does not include any instructions specifically for version 3.3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/migration/